# Auto increment gap in percona xtradb cluster master master setup

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona, galera, master-master-replication

I was using mariadb 5.5 before but now I have upgraded it and using percona xtradb cluster 5.6
I have 3 nodes cluster. I am only using single node for read and write.

I saw some increment gaps in ids so i had to turn off wsrep auto increment control.

I am still confused about innodb_autoinc_lock_mode which is 2 and bin log format is Row.

Is it safe to make it 1 to avoid gaps issue since we are only using single node for write and read?

Thanks

Comment: It is unwise to worry about auto_increment issues.  Are you threatening to run out of ids?  Is your application bothered by the gaps.

Comment: Actually, my application does not behave correctly when there is a gap in increments. I want to keep my application run smoothly as it was before on mariadb 5.5

Comment: Are there any pitfalls if i change innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 1 in pxc?

Answer (score 0):

Galera (hence PXC) prefers `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2`.  I don't know whether this is a "requirement" or just "advisory".  Keep in mind that conflicts with other nodes are not caught until `COMMIT`, and the AI value has already been grabbed.  Without `2`, two different nodes might grab the same AI value, thereby adding to the conflict?

Comment: So using 2 will only be beneficial if i m writing on multiple nodes at the same time. And 1 will be ok if using single node?

Comment: If you are writing to multiple nodes there will be a case where inserts happen on both nodes trying to insert the same id, they will fail certification and you'll have a gap. There are may way's a gap can occur, especially with a clustered system. Application changes is the only real certain way to fix this.